# How to show received data as username in drawer Navigation in react native?

Tags: reactjs, navigation-drawer, react-native, react-native-navigation

[after logging in I received the username and user picture so, how can I display that as shown in the figure below, using react native Drawer Navigation,  please Help me ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZg7q.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show what you have tried so far and what problems you get.

Comment: I mean .. I have stored data in a syncStorage like user name and image .. but I can't reach to these data in contentComponent in drawer navigation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make custom drawer component like this below.
First, initialize DrawerNavigator like this

```
const AppScreens = DrawerNavigator(
{
    Screen1: Screen1,
    Screen2: Screen2,
},{
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
    'drawerOpenRoute': 'DrawerOpen',
    'drawerCloseRoute': 'DrawerClose',
    'drawerToggleRoute': 'DrawerToggle',
    navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
});
```

then, make your custom drawer here

```
const CustomDrawerComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Image source={{uri: 'path/to/image'}} style={{width: 100, height: 50}}/>
            <Text>Your name</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

if you want to fetch name from cache then you can use AsyncStorage here, and navigation prop can be found by using `props.navigation`.